# What do the .forEach statements below do?

Tags: javascript, three.js

What do the two forEach statements below do? Is 'col' a built-in property for arrays?

```
var width = data.length, height = data[0].length;
    data.forEach(function(col){
    col.forEach(function(val){
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(val.x,val.y,val.z))
        colors.push(getColor(2.5,0,val.z));
    });
    });
```

In case some of the earlier code is required:

```
var data = new Array();
    for(var x=BIGIN;x<END;x++){
    var row = [];
    for(var y=BIGIN;y<END;y++){
        z = 2.5*(Math.cos(Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y))+1);
        row.push({x: x, y: y, z: z});
    }
    data.push(row);
    }
```

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterates over an array, just like a `for` loop.

```
array.forEach(function( indice ) {});
```

`data` is an **array of arrays**, `col` is the passed argument from the first `forEach`, so the second `forEach` iterates arrays inside `data`.

It's obvious in the code that creates `data` as well

```
var data = []; // data is an array
...
var row = [];  // row is an array
for(var ...){
    // do stuff
}
data.push(row); // put one array inside the other
```

and then it's iterated

```
data.forEach(function(col){ // <- col is passed as the argument
    col.forEach(function(val){
        // do stuff
    });
});
```